# Logic problem to solve with python (or any other programming language)

Tags: math, logic, combinations

I have to solve this real problem, it seemed trivial to me at first but I am having difficulty and I don't have much time to solve it. I would like to solve it possibly with python so then I can print the result to a csv.
This is the problem:

### Problem

*7 employees must divide the work shifts (M,A,N, morning afternoon and night) over 7 weeks.*
*Each day of the 49 days must have a different employee for each shift.( e.g. day1: M:employee 1, A:employee 3, N:employee 6 )*

*Each employee works  weekday/time slot only 1 time in the 49-day cycle (e.g. employee 1 does 1 Monday morning, 1 Monday afternoon, 1 Monday night, 1 Tuesday morning etc)*

*If an employee works a night shift, it cannot work shifts on the next 2 days.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping shift (M, A, N) to (0, 1, 2) with variable `s`, day (Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday) to (0, 1, ..., 6) with variable `d`, and week in variable `w`, you can use the formula `(w+d-s)%7+1` to get the employee assigned to shift `w,d,s` (`%` is the modulo operator).

(in some languages like C++, you might have to add 7 in the parentheses if modulo of negative numbers outputs a negative number)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With your solution I can satisfy all the constraints except the last one. I tried with Z3 adding all the constraints but the problem has no solutions.

Comment: sorry I made a typo, I corrected it and I think it should now work for all the constraints